# Установка фокуса ввода на контрол winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Существует ли метод, который задает фокус ввода элемента управления?

Comment: Вы хотите получить общий метод, который бы устанавливал бы фокус на контрол переданный как аргумент? Вам же их надо в этом методе каким-то образом отличать друг от друга. Я не пишу под WinForms, но вот в Wpf есть свойство `Tag`, с его помощью можно различать контролы. Думаю в WinForms должно быть нечто подобное.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используй метод [`Control.Focus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек.